# Delete duplicate rows with lowest values in another column in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates, mariadb

I'm newbie, and I'm trying to delete duplicate rows with highest value in another column,

[This is My database and result of below query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rc0d.png)

```
SELECT file_id,src,dst,durations,date_time, COUNT(*), MAX(durations) as 
Max_durations
FROM C2
WHERE durations in (
    SELECT max(durations)
    FROM C2
    GROUP BY src, dst
    HAVING COUNT(*) >1)
GROUP BY src,dst
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Now I want to remove Duplicate rows but keep rows that have maximum duration or equal Max_duration column and if have same duration delete one of them.

How can i do it...?

| src | dst | duration | COUNT | Max_duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12014504264 | 9726341011 | 464 | 20 | 684 |
| 12014504264 | 9726645434 | 320 | 8 | 875 |
| 12014556435 | 9726876431 | 765 | 4 | 900 |
| 12014576565 | 9726347656 | 43 | 7 | 600 |
| 12014508754 | 9726344537 | 233 | 2 | 233 |
| 12014764532 | 9726877654 | 655 | 2 | 54 |
| 12014587875 | 9726645443 | 1345 | 5 | 982 |
| 12014654536 | 9726766433 | 73 | 2 | 84 |

Comment: Show some examples?  As text, please, not images.  "if have same duration" is particularly unclear

Comment: oh, is it supposed to be "if have same duration delete *one* of them"?

Comment: does C2 have a primary key?  please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table C2;` and `select version();`

Comment: Yes, it's has, 
10.4.21-MariaDB

CREATE TABLE `C2` (
  `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `src` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `dst` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `durations` int(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `remark` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive','no_conditions') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  `ref_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1661924 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to actually delete rows from the table, not just have a query that omits certain rows:

To do this, just self-join with a row that would be preferred to the current one, so only rows where that is found are deleted:

```
delete C2
from C2
join C2 preferred on
    preferred.src=C2.src and
    preferred.dst=C2.dst and
    preferred.durations >= C2.durations and
    (preferred.durations > C2.durations or preferred.file_id < C2.file_id)
```

But to do this, you need some unique column to establish a precedence between multiple rows with the maximum duration; here I am using file_id and keeping the row with the lowest file_id.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but what should I use instead preferred...?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  "preferred" is an alias I am giving C2 for the join.  when you use the same table more than once in a query, you usually have to give one or more of the places you use it an alias, which can be anything

Comment: sorry, I got an error, I thought should use something else, but now I run this query on  Navicat and my database is local but stay on running and has no result...! after 2 hours

Comment: ouch.  if you interrupt it it may take that long again just to undo what it's done so far.  if you do interrupt it, it will likely go much faster if you `alter table C2 add index (src,dst,durations);` first

Comment: wow, Thank you so much for your help... that worked...   